# How can I return an object enriched using NodeJS on Lambda to an API POST request

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, post, aws-lambda

I am developing on AWS using Lambda/NodeJS. In response to a POST request I am trying to return a data object which I enrich with presigned URL's to get access to images on S3. The problem is return the data so it is actually returned as a response from the API. I know it's an async problem, but haven't been able to solve it so far. Any help is very much appreciated.

I have the following code:

```
{
    {
        docClient.query(dbparams, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                _response = buildOutput(500, err);
                return callback(_response, null);
            } else {
                dataObj = data.Items;
                var createOutput = function (callback) {
                    async.forEach(dataObj, function (item, callback) {
                        setObjectUrl(item, function (err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                            return callback(undefined, data);
                        });
                    });
                };

                createOutput(function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
                _response = buildOutput(200, data);
                return callback(null, _response);
            }
        });
    }
}


function setObjectUrl(data, callback) {
    var s3params = {
        Bucket: s3Bucket,
        Key: 'avatars/' + data.username + '.jpg'
    };

    S3.headObject(s3params, function (err, metadata) {
        if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {
            //console.log('geen url voor deze gebruiker gevonden');
        } else {
            data["url"] = S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3params);
        }
        return callback(data);
    });
}

function buildOutput(statusCode, data) {
    let _response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    return _response;
}
```

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: Sorry, just did.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the data, but I can explain a little bit more about the output I am getting. I get the reponse from the data object which is called back from the docClient.query(dbparams, function (err, data).

What I want is the data from the return callback(data); in the function setObjectUrl(data, callback).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I eventually solved it. Thanks for your help.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const util = require('util');

// Create reference to S3 client
var S3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    apiversion: '2006-03-01'
});

// Lambda provided credentials
let creds = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS'); 
const dynamoConfig = {
    credentials: creds,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
};

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(dynamoConfig);
const dynamoDBGetAsync = util.promisify(dynamoDB.query).bind(dynamoDB);

// some variables we need
const ddbTable = 'database';
var _response;
var s3Bucket = 'photo-bucket';

module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    if (event.resource === '/' && event.httpMethod === "GET") {
        const username = event.queryStringParameters.userid;

        var params = {
            TableName: ddbTable,
            IndexName: 'userid-index',
            KeyConditionExpression: "#uid = :uid",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#uid": "userid"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":uid": username
            }
        };

        let result= await dynamoDBGetAsync(params);
        for (let item of result.Items) {
            if (item.username !== undefined ||  null) {
                item.url = await getObjectUrl(item);
            }
        }
        _response = buildOutput(200, result);
        return callback(null, _response);
    }
};

function getObjectUrl(data) {
    console.log("Data: " +JSON.stringify(data));
    const s3params = {
        Bucket: s3Bucket,
        Key: 'avatars/' + data.username + '.jpg'
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        S3.headObject(s3params, function (err, metadata) {
            console.log('parameters: ' + JSON.stringify(s3params));
            if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            } else {
                const signedUrl = S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3params);
                console.log(signedUrl);
                resolve(signedUrl);
            }
         });
     });
}

function buildOutput(statusCode, data) {
    let _response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    return _response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke lambda's callback once all of your async calls are done. There are some different options to fix your code, but I'd suggest to use promises and async/await. This would not only make your code work, but also make it more readable and help to avoid callback hell.

You'll need to wrap your S3 call in promise:

```
function getObjectUrl(data) {
    const s3params = {
        Bucket: s3Bucket,
        Key: 'avatars/' + data.username + '.jpg'
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        S3.headObject(s3params, function (err, metadata) {
            if (err) {
                //handle error
            } else {
                const signedUrl = S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3params);
                resolve(signedUrl);
            }
         });
     });
}
```

After that you'd just need to call your promisified function in loop:

```
for(let item of data.Items) {
    item.url = await getObjectUrl(data);
}
```

Just don't forget to make your main function async and configure your lambda to use NodeJS 8.10

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. When I use this code in Lambda with NodeJS 8.10, I get a parsing error: unexpected token getObjectUrl right after the await. I have made my main function async. Note. I've been trying to solving the problem using aync await and ran into the same problem... Any suggestions?

Comment: That's strange, async/await works perfectly well with NodeJS 8.10 on lambda. Could you post the part of your code with your async lambda handler?

Comment: Sasha, I think the problem is that I have to make the docClient.query async, not the main, as this is where the for loop will be. Trying to figure out how to make docClient.query async...

Comment: Which might nog be possible because of it's inherent asynchronous nature.

Comment: oh, I see. What you want to do is not making docClient async, it's already async. What you actually need to do is to make the method promisified.  In nodejs 8 there is an easy and clean way to do it: const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);
result = await stat('.');

Comment: Okay, what I have done is:
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(dynamoConfig);
const dynamoDBGetAsync = util.promisify(dynamoDB.query).bind(dynamoDB);

and then:

let result= await dynamoDBGetAsync(params);
        for (let item of result.Items) {
                item.url = await getObjectUrl(item);
        }

which seems to be what I need, but now result in an S3 error "statusCode":404,"retryable":

Comment: You should debug which file url  and bucket are passed as s3 params, and check if keys are ok and you do actually have files by those keys